# CSS Display Issue in IE, looks fine in FF and can't track it down

Tags: php, css, browser

In this link the top right blue checkbox search button displays perfect in FF but is totally too high in IE in relation to the searchbox and links to the left of it...I've tried tracking down in IE how to adjust...can somebody please take a peek and see what I am missing?  Thanks in advance!

URL: http://tinyurl.com/859n6wf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have a form with 2 inline tags (links) and 2 input tags wrapped into a form tag. There is an easy way you can try and set to that input margin-bottom:-8px; 
I think this will fix it. But I suggest you do some rework on your html there, and use a box model of HTML (use float,paddings borders for separators rather than    |   ). 
This kind of situation will always be treated different by browsers, because you're not using a box model

Comment: thanks!  I am going to re-work this but it is a quick fix for now.  thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? If you're talking about IE7 or lower it may be related to styling of elements using attribute selectors like `input[type="text"]` which those versions don't support (at least not without help from javascript libraries like ie7.js).